# How to chose whether we deploy a jar or a war in Spring-Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, war

What I understand is we can deploy a spring-boot application as a jar and as a war as well. What I don't understand is when should we go with a jar and a war ? I am talking about spring-boot web apps.

stack overflow

Answer (score 3):

Both ways are equivalent technological wise.

JAR is a preferable way of deploying spring boot application, so consider it it as a first bet.

WAR is required if you already have java web servers (tomcats) managed by people who don't want/need to adopt a new / another way of deployment.
Usually this happens in large organizations or organizations with a dedicated IT / adminstration/ops department (many names exist for this), but essentially these are people who are responsible for deployment of the application.

Comment: So, you mean technically we don't achieve anything using a jar instead of war?

Comment: Technically not, but its much more convenient to deal with one jar devops wise.

Comment: If I was deploying a React / some other JavaScript front-end which is served from the same port and I created this, for this I could still use jar or war correct ? If I had Thymeleaf as a template, would that also work with JAR ?

Comment: both war and jar can be used in this case. Again, technologically wise its the same. In fact the jar usually includes an embedded web server that can serve js/css/html files.